# Want to get request from web page, html object error

Tags: vba, api

Now code works fine, with api get request. Anyone can benefit from it.

```
Sub AskApi()
Dim HTMLDOC As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLTABLES As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLTABLE As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLDIV As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableSection As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim Unit As String
Dim Rate, DateR As String
Dim TableCellCount, RowNum As Integer
Dim inputdate_from, inputdate_to, inputcurr_val As Variant

inputdate_from = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PrimoPagina").Range("A3").Value
inputdate_to = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PrimoPagina").Range("E3").Value
inputcurr_val = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PrimoPagina").Range("B1").Value
If inputcurr_val = "BLG" Then
inputcurr_val = "R01100"
Else
inputcurr_val = "R01239" 'EUR
End If


    Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim reqURL As String
    
    reqURL = "https://www.cbr.ru/eng/currency_base/dynamics/?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.so=1&UniDbQuery.mode=1&UniDbQuery.date_req1=&UniDbQuery.date_req2=&UniDbQuery.VAL_NM_RQ=" & inputcurr_val & "&UniDbQuery.From=" & inputdate_from & "&UniDbQuery.To=" & inputdate_to
    req.Open "GET", reqURL, False
    
    req.send
    
    If req.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox req.Status & " - " & req.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

The error line was below. But with assistance from Tim, I assigned variable to HTMLDOC

```
 Set HTMLDOC = CreateObject("htmlfile")
'    ' assign the returned text to a HTML document
    HTMLDOC.body.innerHTML = req.responseText
 Set HTMLTABLES = HTMLDOC.getElementsByClassName("data")
For Each HTMLTABLE In HTMLTABLES 'Table
    For Each TableSection In HTMLTABLE.Children 'Body
            For Each TableRow In TableSection.Children
                RowText = ""
                TableCellCount = 1
                For Each TableCell In TableRow.Children
                    If TableCellCount = 1 Then DateR = TableCell.innerText
                    If TableCellCount = 2 Then Unit = TableCell.innerText
                    If TableCellCount = 3 Then Rate = TableCell.innerText
                    TableCellCount = TableCellCount + 1
                Next TableCell
                Debug.Print Unit, Rate
                
                RowNum = RowNum + 1
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results").Cells(RowNum, 3).Value = Unit
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results").Cells(RowNum, 2).Value = Rate
               ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results").Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = DateR
                
            Next TableRow
    Next TableSection
Next

    
End Sub
```

I have changed the places from below line to above, some variables(input variables) now the code works! Thanks to comment from Tim Williams. Before, I did not assign req.requestText to any variable.

Comment: `Set HTMLDOC = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument`  But you're not doing anything with `req.responseText` other than printing it out.

Comment: I have edited code, assigned variable. But now it gives result but different

Comment: "result but different" is not a very useful description of the specific problem you're having with your code.  What *exactly* is happening or not happening when your code runs, and how is it different from what you expect to happen?

Comment: Hey Tim, after assigning now it works fine actually. I just changed variable declarations place from below to upper part. Thanks@TimWilliams